# What generates this code string in the middle of my URL?

Tags: asp.net

What makes this generated code string in the middle of a path:
/Applications/(S(0vgzvk45p0v3i355faksetve))/Graduate/Default.aspx
Each time I run the program, a new coded string in the middle like this appears.
I cannot find in the code where this is done.

Comment: Are you using "cookieless sessions"?

Comment: Check your web.config for `<sessionState cookieless="true"/>`